# How to set image in pdf header itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

hi i am trying to set two images in pdf header, but the images are stretched, i can't set height of images as it is saying height is only read only property. the actual height of image is 80px and width is 120px. but the images are stretching how to avoid stretching.

my code is:

```
 public partial class MyEvent : PdfPageEventHelper
    {

        iTextSharp.text.Image image1;
        iTextSharp.text.Image image2;
        PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(3);

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ReportManager.Properties.Settings.Default.RMCompanyLogo);

            image1.SetAbsolutePosition(20, (document.PageSize.Height - 120));
            image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ReportManager.Properties.Settings.Default.RMCompanyLogoOne);
            image2.SetAbsolutePosition((document.PageSize.Width) - (image2.Width + 20), 20);

            //header.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);

        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {


            PdfPTable tbHeader = new PdfPTable(3);
            tbHeader.AddCell(image1);
            tbHeader.AddCell("Report Name");
            tbHeader.AddCell(image2);

            tbHeader.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 20;
            tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, document.PageSize.Height - 15, writer.DirectContent);
        }

    }
```

i am getting result as below:

[image]

Comment: Please read the official documentation, more specifically: [How to resize an Image to fit it into a PdfPCell?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-resize-image-fit-it-pdfpcell) In that question, some one uses the method you use and he complains that the image isn't scale. You are using the method he should have used, and you complain that the image is scaled. Both use cases are valid, so iText provides both options. It beats me why people don't use the method they need. Maybe it's because they never read the documentation.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Did you inform Adidas that a commercial license is required?

Comment: sorry sir, just for the sake of exmaple i have uploaded the adidas logo, i just wanted to show the logo on the left and right, its not yet solved.

Comment: 1. Did you try changing your code based on the information I shared. If so, what went wrong? If not, why not? 2. You can safely admit that you're working for Adidas. You could get better support if we'd know which company we're helping. Now you are just an anonymous person to us. The threshold to help someone we don't know is higher than the threshold to help someone we don't know.